# Recording with Eggplant?

Tags: eggplant

When a coded UI test in Eggplant fails, it gives a screenshot of exactly where the script failed at. I want more than just a screenshot, however.  I want a video recording of the test running, so I can have a better idea of why the test is failing.

Is there feature in Eggplant that allows me to video record a test?  Or maybe there is some way SenseTalk or an Eggplant extension that can do this for me and log it in a .wav file?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas:

- Find a screen-capture tool that you can run from a batch file, and
  call that batch file in your eggPlant Functional script. (I found
  several options by searching for "start screen recording from batch
  file".) The SenseTalk command would look like this: *Shell
  "StartRecording.bat"*.
- If you are running eggPlant Functional on Mac, you can try the
  deprecated *StartMovie* and *StopMovie* commands.

Happy Scripting,

Pamela

Answer (score 0):

Eggplant has built-in recording features.

You no longer need to be on a Mac to record a movie; any machine running Eggplant on any SUT can record a movie.

[From the documentation:](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/using/epf-recording-movies.htm)

```
StartMovie "/path/to/record/the/movie"
//Section of test script you want to record
StopMovie
```

This will save the video as an .mkv file, which can be opened in [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), if nothing else.